# NSManagedObjectContext objectWithId not returning an object despite valid objectId

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data structure of persistent store <-> main thread context <-> private thread contexts (used as scratchpads).

My user presses 'Save' after creating and configuring a magazine object on a 'private thread'/scratchpad context.

I fetch the currently logged in account from the main thread context because the new magazine which is to be created must be assigned an account.

```
Account* accountForMagazine = [self.accountsConnector getSelectedAccount];
NSLog(@"object id: %@",accountForMagazine.objectID);
```

The object id NSLog output is:

```
0xa677790 <x-coredata://F635CE5A-C335-48F0-BB27-61B7D9XXXXD8/Account/p4>
```

So its a permanent id and that tells me that the object is in the persistent store.

I then switch over to the private thread (databaseConnector is just a wrapper around a managed object context on a private thread) and try to bring that account object onto the thread so it can be assigned to the magazine object which is going to be saved.

```
[self.databaseConnector executeOnCorrectThread:^
{
    Account* account = (Account*)[self.databaseConnector.getContext objectWithID:accountForMagazine.objectID];
    self.magazine.account = account;
    if(!account) { NSLog(@"nil account"); }
    [self.databaseConnector save];
}
```

The problem im having is that although the new magazine objects are being saved and are making it to the persistent store, none of them are connected to an account! And of course, the NSLog statement is shown each time - saying that the account object on this thread is nil.

So even though I have a valid objectId and therefore the object exists in the persistent store, I am not getting an account object on the private thread through objectWithId.

Any ideas why that is?

Thanks

Vb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something in there is `nil` that you don't expect to be `nil`.

Here's why: `objectWithID:` *always* returns an object. But you're getting `nil`. The most likely reason is that `self.databaseConnector.getContext` is actually returning `nil` in that block. It might be that `accountForMagazine` is *also* `nil` but if that was the only unexpected `nil` then your app would be crashing (can't pass `nil` to that method and live).

Comment: I think you are onto something here since objectWithID: should throw an exception if the object with given ID did not exist.